# Git - how to force sync remote from local

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am a newbie with git. I have read some papers but I have some doubts.
I have read some similar post that seem to be duplicated of my problem and I try that solutions proposed. But, no look, It not solved my problem

I have a remote repository and I´d like to force it to sync my local files.
I believe the remote is out-of-date. I have only a branch master.

I had a problem when I tried to push saying "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits". I did 
`git reset --hard origin/master` and It solved that problem.

Now, I´d like to force the remote branch master repository to update with my local files.

I have used `git push origin master -f`. The results are "everything up-to-date", but I need to force the update of remote repository with the local files, because I am no sure if it is really updated.

Reflog Output:

```
Luiz@Dell-Sala MINGW64 /c/AppProg/NH (master)
git reflog
5e63abf (HEAD -> master, origin/master) HEAD@{0}: commit: <U+009B>23_02_2019
edc9596 HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to origin/master
1d81b58 HEAD@{2}: commit: <U+009B>22_02_2019
7a4a5cd HEAD@{3}: reset: moving to HEAD
7a4a5cd HEAD@{4}: commit: <U+009B>22_02_2019
f54f851 HEAD@{5}: reset: moving to HEAD
f54f851 HEAD@{6}: commit: tiss 30303
edc9596 HEAD@{7}: commit: novas alteracoes 23_09_2017
07c87c3 HEAD@{8}: commit: commit 14092016
b894041 HEAD@{9}: commit: mudancas em 05092016
555bdae HEAD@{10}: commit: mudancas em 29082016v1
028d122 HEAD@{11}: commit: mudancas em 29082016
c118805 HEAD@{12}: commit: mudanças em 10_08_2016
e34cf58 HEAD@{13}: commit (initial): #1 - Codigo inicial postado

Luiz@Dell-Sala MINGW64 /c/AppProg/NH (master)
```

Comment: That’s because you “got rid” of your commits when you reset. You can get back to them, but you’ll need to resolve the first issue again. This time don’t use reset.

Comment: Thank you, please how I solve it. Can you tell me which comands I have to use?

Comment: This is a suggestion, not an answer... look at `git reflog` to find your commits, then fetch, then merge origin/master _into_ your branch.

Comment: Also to answer your question title, you are synced with the remote. When you reset you moved your local branch to be where the remote said it should be.

Comment: Sorry, I am lost. I have posted the reflog output

Comment: So, I dont need to do nothing, because I am already synced with the remote?

Comment: You are synced with the remote, but any work you did before (the “3 ahead of origin”) is not there. If you don’t want it, then you’re fine.

Comment: I need to put in the remote  all works that I did, including the "3 ahead of origin". How could I do that?

Comment: In the reflog, find the commit ID (the six numbers and letters on the left) using the commit message you gave to your most recent commit. Then reset hard to that commit, then fetch origin, then _merge origin into your branch_.

Comment: It seems complicated to me. I´m afraid make some error and substitute my local files with old files from remote.

Answer (score 1):

> I had a problem when I tried to push saying "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits".

That is not a "problem"; that is normal output from git (usually `git status`) telling you that you have local changes that could be sync'd to the remote.  The correct procedure at this point, if you wanted to update the remote with your local changes, is

```
git push
```

If this produced an error message, then we'd need to see *that* message to advise further.

> I did  git reset --hard origin/master and It solved that problem.

What you told git to do here is to sync the current local branch (`master`) with the remote branch - removing all the local changes.  This removes the "branch is ahead" message precisely because it means that there is nothing to push anymore.

From comments it was suggested that you use the reflog, and you've added reflog output.  Now what that output shows you is a history of every time the `HEAD` ref has moved.  Normally that's because of things like commits, checkouts, or in this case a reset.  So the line

```
edc9596 HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to origin/master
```

shows specifically when you reset the local `master` to match the remote tracking ref `origin/master`, and what you probably want to do is to move local `master` back to the state before this

Complicating things, though, you made another commit after doing this, shown by

```
5e63abf (HEAD -> master, origin/master) HEAD@{0}: commit: <U+009B>23_02_2019
```

Before I continue, I want to emphasize - the following commands are based on the above reflog output.  If you have done anything since then that would add to the reflog - such as more commits, checkouts, etc. - then you need to rerun `git reflog` and adjust the commands you use accordingly.

Specifically, I'm going to refer to `HEAD@2`; that's because in the reflog output `HEAD@1` refers to the result of the `reset`, so you want to go *one state further back* - and `HEAD@2` is the state before `HEAD@1`.

So:

If the commit you made after the reset represents new changes that need to be preserved, then you would say

```
git branch temp
git reset --hard HEAD@{2}
git rebase --onto master origin/master temp
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only temp
git branch -d temp
```

If the commit is not needed - if it was just an attempt to restore some of the other local changes or something - then you only need

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{2}
```